# Visual Studio refuses to plug DLL Reference

Tags: visual-studio, reference, active-directory

I work under Visual Studio 2019 Community. Its behaviour looks a bit queer to me, since I face once more a problem I didn't meet on Visual Studio 2015:

In a C# code file dedicated to handle an Active Directory, I mention these references:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

in the References of the application, I have added

```
System.DirectoryServices
```

If I ask Visual Studio to explore that DLL, I can see all its content in the object explorer:
3 namespaces, each one containing lots of functions, and all that is displayed by the explorer of the application. So I don't understand why I can't start my app because of this message:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Well, I feel like I didn't omit the reference, since it's visible in the application references. Moreover, I never met that problem with the former versions of Visual Studio. So, if you know the explanation of this behaviour, I'd be grateful if you can let me know.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? VS2015 was all about .NET Framework, but today VS2019 is mainly for .NET Core. The two platforms differ so much that `System.DirectoryServices` won't be available in the latter if you don't configure further.

Comment: Thank you for that indication, so where can I find a document guide to configure VS 2019 properly in order to use Active Directory ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack For .NET Core based projects, you need to follow this.

Answer (score 1):

Also Please check below points,if required
(If already done omit respective steps or you may remove and install again. )

1. Right click on References under your solution.
2. Select Add Reference. The reference can be found under the Framework Assemblies list. Select System.DirectoryServices and click Add.
3. After you add your directory services reference, right click on the reference and go to properties. Set `"CopyLocal" to true`.
4. You may also need to add the Reference `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` as well.Then add these two namespaces in the project.
5. Then Check if the assemblies are present in web.config file (version according to your .net framework)

```html
<compilation debug="false" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" targetFramework="4.7">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</assemblies>
</compilation>
```

6. Check if the bin folder has the reference System.DirectoryServices  ,if not copy that System.DirectoryServices.dll and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll in the bin folder .

(which maybe present in C:\ProgramFiles\Reference\Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\version)